# How to implement IF-Else condition in JoltTransformJson processor in NiFi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Can anyone help how to implement if else conditons in jolt transforms,

The conditions is:

1. If `name is null` and `IsEligible is false` then `SSP value is 0`.
2. If `name is not null` and `IsEligible is true` then `SSP_I value needs to assigned to SSP field`.

Input:

```json
{
  "IsEligible" : false,
  "Name" : null,
  "SSP" : "15.00",
  "SSP_I" : "5.00"
}
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
  "IsEligible" : false,
  "Name" : null,
  "SSP" : "0",
  "SSP_I" : "5.00"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use predefined ***notNull*** and ***isNull*** predefined functions within **modify**,

and conditional logic within **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=toString",
      "N1": ["=notNull(@(1,Name))", "NuLl"],
      "N2": ["=isNull(@(1,Name))", "NotNuLl"],
      "Cond": "=concat(@(1,N1),'_',@(1,N2),'_',@(1,IsEligible))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "IsEligible|Name|SSP_I": "&",
      "Cond": {
        "*NotNuLl*true": {
          "@2,SSP_I": "SSP"
        },
        "NuLl*false": {
          "#0": "SSP"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```